# Make <button> and <a> act the same way in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a little bit of a problem, where I can't get 3 buttons (where 2 of them are `<a>` Tags and one is a `<button>` Tag) to act in the same way. My current approach looks like this:

---

HTML:

```
<div id="legButtons">
    <p>Legal Information:</p>
    <button id="contactBut" class="ui-btn ui-icon-mail ui-btn-icon-left legalButton" onclick="support()">Contact</button>
    <a id="termsBut" href="#terms" class="ui-btn ui-icon-shop ui-btn-icon-left legalButton">Terms</a>
    <a id="privacyBut" href="#privacy" class="ui-btn ui-icon-lock ui-btn-icon-left legalButton">Privacy</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#legButtons {
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
#legButtons a.legalButton {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

#legButtons button.legalButton {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

---

What happens is that the `<button>` is rendered in a line above the `<a>` elements. Here an according JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/g6wexby7/1/

I can fix this with adding `float: left`to the element, but than the whole point of inline block + `text-align: center` doesn't work anymore. Is there another way to fix this, while keeping the center align working?

Comment: hey display: flex; may work for you just add to the following selector's style #legButtons  may this work for you

Answer (score 0):

try to override below class that might help

```
.ui-btn {
   overflow: unset;
}
```

Comment: This does work in Desktop Browsers, but on a mobile one I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure why, but if you remove/override "overflow: hidden" from .ui-btn they will align.

Comment: This does work in Desktop Browsers, but on a mobile one I still have the same problem.

Comment: I just tested it on a mobile Chrome without issue. They wrap and you end up with two on top and one on the next line, but that's just how the layout works at that resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the overflow properties in the class name of

```
.ui-btn {
font-size: 16px;
    margin: .5em 0;
    padding: .7em 1em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: This does work in Desktop Browsers, but on a mobile one I still have the same problem.